# How i exclude part of code being obfuscated by ConfuserEx?

Tags: c#, confuserex

Im looking to how i can exclude a line of code in my project, but all i found is how to exclude a complete namespace, can you help me ?

Answer (score 3):

.NET has an attribute called [ObfuscationAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.obfuscationattribute?view=netcore-3.1), which has an [Exclude](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.obfuscationattribute.exclude?view=netcore-3.1#System_Reflection_ObfuscationAttribute_Exclude) property.

The documentation for `Exclude` says:

> Gets or sets a Boolean value indicating whether the obfuscation tool should exclude the type or member from obfuscation.

You should be able to add `[Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]` to the member(s) you want to exclude. If the obfuscator tool you're using properly respect this attribute (ConfuserEx should be respecting this AFAIK), it should get the work done.

Example:

```
[Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]
public class MyClass
{
    [Obfuscation(Exclude = true)] 
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        Value1,
        Value2,
    }

    [Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]    
    public void MyFunction(MyEnum e_Enum)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i dont know how to use this [Obfuscation(Exclude = true)], where to add it ? i just want to exclude a line of code, actually in the file Program.cs

Comment: @JuulFan Extract this one line of code into a method, and put `[Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]` just above the method.

Comment: And obviously, don't forget `using System.Reflection;`

Comment: i did it it doesnt work :(      
[System.Reflection.Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]
        static void notObsfuscate()
        {

Comment: You need to explain more on *how* it doesn't work. Did you get a compile-error? can you show it? did it compile successfully but ConfuserEx didn't exclude it?

Comment: Also i just add the next code to AssemblyInfo.cs and it works, but im worry about what exactly do this code -> [assembly: Obfuscation(Exclude = false, Feature = "packer:compressor")]

Comment: @JuulFan I think it should disable a feature called "packer:compressor" for the entire assembly, not only for the one line you want to exclude.

Comment: Yes, back to the problem,  the solution that you post sounds good, just need to make it works, i did what you post, and doesnt work, and if i compile without using confuserex then works, but then when i compile and use confuserex it doesnt work.

Comment: @JuulFan Anything you did wrong. For me it works perfectly. Just add the attribute to your class and it's functions that you want to remain with original names.